# Need to create an AMI from a running AWS instance (windows)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

Is it possible to create an AMI from an EBS backed windows instance without disruption of service? When i click on the "create instance" selection from the instance actions menu, will it pause my running instance?

Comment: Do you want to create an AMI or a new EC2 instance, or both ?  It's not clear to me from your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an image without shutting down your server by using the "--no-reboot" option with the [ec2-create-image](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html) command line tool.

You can do the same thing using the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) by doing something similar to:

```
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey);

var createImageRequest = new CreateImageRequest
{
    InstanceId = "<YOUR INSTANCE ID>",
    NoReboot = true
};


var createImageResponse = ec2Client.CreateImage(createImageRequest);
```

Bear in mind that when you image an instance using the --no-reboot option, it is imaged without cleanly shutting down the image. The next time you start your server based on this image, the Shutdown Event Tracker will pop up wondering why you lost power.

Answer (score 0):

While the Windows instance is being bundled, it will be offline